# How to exit the fullscreen mode in TightVNC embedded in TightVNC

Tags: tightvnc

For some reasons I work on remote server, the access is as follows:

I reach the Machine1 (M1) using the TightVNC Viewer, from there I reach the M2 using RDP, from there I use the TightVNC again to reach my destination server M3.

I do need to use the TightVNC for M3 in fullscreen mode, so I use the respective button in the toolbar to enter it.

When I finish my work, I can't minimise M3 back as Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F combination makes me go to/from fullsreen mode for M1 TightVNC Viewer.

Currently I have to Reboot M3 and then logoff from M2.

I also can't use batch for M3 with the code:

```
net stop "TightVNC Server"

net start "TightVNC Server"
```

as I don't have admin credentials there.

Are there any other ways to Minimise the M3 TightVNC?

Thank you!

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use short-cut:

```
Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F
```

to exit the full screen mode.

Comment: this combo worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you can kill the fullscreened M3 TightVNC process (send Ctrl+Alt+Del?), then you can launch TightVNC in M2 again, but in the New TightVNC Connection window, before hitting Connect hit the Options button and deselect the Full-screen mode checkbox in the Display section.

Answer (score 0):

I use xtightvncviewer nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn -fullscreen to start and then Alt-F4 seems to work .. it just exits the tightvnc view window and goes back to desktop for me